# Trigger a delayed hover event with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to trigger a delayed hover event:

```
$(".graphic").delay(500).trigger('mouseover').trigger('mouseout');
```

But the delay is being ignored.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) only affects the animation queue, but [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) is synchronous. You can use [queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) to schedule a function triggering the events after the delay:

```
$(".graphic").delay(500).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).trigger("mouseover").trigger("mouseout");
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.delay()` method is best for delaying **between queued jQuery effects**.

To delay the initial effect, use `setTimeout()` function. By the way, you could use `mouseover()` instead of `trigger('mouseover')`

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $(".graphic").mouseover().mouseout();
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

The [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) says:

> Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not use the effects queue.

Maybe you can set a timer, that will trigger mouseover/out after 500 ms using Windows.setTimeout